# powershell pod failing in kubernetes cluster

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I need to run powershell as an container in kubernetes

I am using following deployment file `sample.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: powershell
spec:
  containers:
  - name: powershell
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
```

When I run `kubectl apply -f sample.yaml`

I get the following error on `kubectl get pods`

```
powershell        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3 (50s ago)   92s
```

I did check the log `kubectl logs powershell`

```
PowerShell 7.2.6
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /> ←[?1h
```

But when i run same image as a docker container with following command its working

```
docker run --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
```

Comment: How would you interact with it?  Running a shell as a long-running non-interactive container process doesn't seem that useful.  Do you need to `kubectl run` a debugging pod instead?

Comment: Actually i have to run few commands via java .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep a container for running, you should write like this yaml..

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: powershell
spec:
  containers:
  - name: powershell
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
    command: ["pwsh"]
    args: ["-Command", "Start-Sleep", "3600"]
```

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get pod powershell
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
powershell   1/1     Running   0          3m32s
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl exec -it powershell -- pwsh
PowerShell 7.2.6
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /> date
Thu Oct 13 12:50:24 PM UTC 2022
PS />
```

Answer (score 0):

The docker run the same image by allocating the [interactive shell](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) by using flag `-it`. So that's why the to container keeps running until you exit the command.

To achieve similar in Kubernetes you can use `run` command.

```
kubectl run -i --rm --tty power --image=mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
```

[interactive-bash-pod-within-a-kubernetes](https://gc-taylor.com/blog/2016/10/31/fire-up-an-interactive-bash-pod-within-a-kubernetes-cluster)

Comment: Yes using above command its working , but scenario is i need to run in aws eks and using any kubernetes java client invoke powershell commands